# Can't change destination of 'Take bug report'

Tags: android, debugging

I have an app that crashes on just one android device running 4.4.2. I turned on 'Settings->Developer options ->Take bug report' on the device and it asked me - just the first time- where to send the bug report: I selected 'android email'.

When I reproduced the crash, the device sent an error message: I received the email but the attachment somehow got lost. I tried again- turn on 'Take bug report' and this time it didn't ask where to send the report. I reproduced the crash and got another email without any attachments.

I would like to try sending the bug report to dropbox or gmail, but there doesn't seem to be a way to change the app that handles the bug report: once you have selected 'android mail', you are stuck with it.

Any suggestions for how to get the log?

Comment: Tell us more about the feature 'take bug report' you are using. Where did u turn it on? Is it a app or a library or part of android OS?

Answer (score 0):

When Android stopped allowing apps like CatLog to see the log file (for security reasons, apparently), I tried to use this method of accessing on-device crash logs.

I never managed to get it to work, but whilst researching it I discovered the CustomExceptionHandler feature, which writes crash logs to a folder.

My app can subsequently access the log files and  forward to me: I actually did it using PHP, but you could use email too. You could also write the crash logs to an SD card and then transfer them manually to your computer.

```
private static final String STACK_TRACE_EXTENSION = ".stack";
private static final String CRASHLOG_DIR = "crashlog";
private static File logDir = null;
private static Thread crashLogThread = null;

public static void initialise (Context context) {

    logDir = new File (context.getFilesDir (), CRASHLOG_DIR);
    logDir.mkdirs ();

    if (!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof CustomExceptionHandler)) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler(logDir));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is a cache for "Android Mail", just delete the cache as a default application and when you send another bug report, options for Gmail/Drive and others will reappear.